# How to make post with data class

Tags: kotlin, request, http-post

I have this endpoint with this structure:

```
uri = http://127.0.0.1:9090/tables/mask
```

and this payload:

```
{
   "_id" : "5d66c9b6d5ccf30bd5b6b541",
   "connectionId" : "1967c072-b5cf-4e9e-1c92-c2b49eb771c4",
   "name" : "Customer",
   "columns" : [
       {
           "name" : "FirstName",
           "mask" : true
       },
       {
           "name" : "LastName",
           "mask" : false
       },
       {
           "name" : "City",
           "mask" : false
       },
       {
           "name" : "Phone",
           "mask" : false
       }
   ],
   "parentId" : null
}
```

in my  Kotlin code I have this structure to deserialize:

```
data class ColumnsMaskModel (val name:String, val mask:Boolean )

data class TablesMaskModel (val _id:String, val name:String, val connectionId:String, val columns:MutableList<ColumnsMaskModel?> )
```

and how can I use `TablesMaskModel` to make a HTTP post in Kotlin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need an HTTP client to do that. Data classes themselves has nothing to do with HTTP, they are just data structures. There are a lot of HTTP clients available on Kotlin for JVM:

- [java.net.HttpURLConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)
- Java 9's [HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html)
- [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org)
- [OkHttp](https://square.github.io/okhttp)
- [Ktor](https://ktor.io)

Let's see how to make HTTP requests in Ktor:

```
data class ColumnsMaskModel(val name: String, val mask: Boolean)

data class TablesMaskModel(val _id: String, val name: String, val connectionId: String, val columns: MutableList<ColumnsMaskModel?>)

fun main() = runBlocking {
    val client = HttpClient {
        install(JsonFeature) {
            serializer = JacksonSerializer()
        }
    }

    val result = client.post<String> {
        url("http://httpbin.org/post")
        contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
        body = TablesMaskModel(
            _id = "5d66c9b6d5ccf30bd5b6b541",
            connectionId = "1967c072-b5cf-4e9e-1c92-c2b49eb771c4",
            name = "Customer",
            columns = mutableListOf(
                ColumnsMaskModel(name = "FirstName", mask = true),
                ColumnsMaskModel(name = "LastName", mask = false),
                ColumnsMaskModel(name = "City", mask = false),
                ColumnsMaskModel(name = "Phone", mask = false)
            )
        )
    }

    println(result)

    client.close()
}
```

Note that Ktor uses suspending functions for HTTP requests, so you'll need a coroutine scope, `runBlocking` in this example.

Ktor supports various "backends" for HTTP clients – Apache, Coroutines IO, curl. It also has different "features" to enable on-the-flight payloads serializations and de-serializations, like in the example above.